# python tkinter packing

Tags: python, widget, tkinter, packing

Could someone please explain why when you have an plain widget as one line Code A works

```
Entry(root, width=10).pack(side=LEFT,anchor=W)
```

but when you name it or attach a command to it, Code A no longer works and gives you Error Message B

```
self.my_entry = Entry(root, width=10).pack(side=LEFT,anchor=W)
```

and you must pack using a seperate line?

```
self.my_entry = Entry(root, width=10)
self.my_entry.pack(side=LEFT,anchor=W)
```

Code A

```
self.my_entry.get()
```

Error Message B

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  The widget no longer appears?  Or something else?

Comment: I've updated it with a more concrete example and specific error message

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `pack` method returns `None`. So

```
self.my_label = Label(root, text="My Label").pack(side=LEFT,anchor=W)
```

sets `self.my_label` to `None`. That is why further commands using `self.my_label` no longer work.

You've found the solution; call `pack` on a separate line:

```
self.my_label = Label(root, text="My Label")
self.my_label.pack(side=LEFT,anchor=W)
```